# Plotting multiple species accumulation curves in R

Tags: r

I am trying to plot multiple curves on one plot. I have managed to produce the curves individually but can't get them all on the same plot.

I have tried the *add=TRUE* function which isn't working.

When using this line of code 
*caw<- plot(specaccum(cs, method = "exact"))*
Nothing is saving to the data section on the right. It's just saying NULL (empty). Which could be the issue but I am unsure how to move forward?

Comment: As mentioned above add some code and sample data by editing your question.

Comment: Please use StackOverflow and/or Google before asking e.g. [Create a new ggplot](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggplot.html).